# Combing facet_grid with geom_abline

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I am trying to use `geom_abline` with `facet_grid` where I have 4 months in a categorical variable and 4 lakes in a categorical variable giving a 16 panel grid. I have already built the slopes and intercepts using `coef(summary(lm))` from 4 different `lm` models. Is it possible to specify which panels in the `facet_grid` I want to add the `geom_abline` to? I have added some dummy data to get an idea of what I am trying to do, but think of all 16 panels having multiple data points rather than 4 of them having one..

```
df1 <- data.frame(month =c("May","June","September","October"),
              lake = c("L1","L2","L3","L4"),
              var1 = c(10,9,8,9),
              var2 = c(11,9,8,9)
              )

gridfig <- ggplot(df1, aes(var2,var1))+
  facet_grid(rows = vars(month), cols = vars(lake))+
  geom_point(size = 2)
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you build your model with `lm`, you can use `geom_smooth` to plot the model directly. Here, I used the `mpg` dataset to show you how do it:

```r
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ, y = cty)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    facet_grid(drv ~ cyl) +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks. My only issue is that for one of my lakes, I want the same slope but different intercepts across months, which I specified when I built the models. Any ideas around that?

Comment: I see in this case, can you edit your question to provide a more reproducible example of your dataset and models you have built ?